# Importing pyodbc results as Internal server error in Apache HTTP Server

Tags: python-3.x, apache, pyodbc, sql-server-2017

Executing the cmd as  **c:\>pip install pyodbc** 
"*pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd*" file will be created

> ```
>  Collecting pyodbc   Using cached
>  pyodbc-4.0.21-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl Installing collected packages:
>  pyodbc Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.21
> ```

---

When I try to run in Apache24 Server the below code results in **Internal Server Error**

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP;"
                      "Database=demo2017;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Running in python shell as
     **C:\Apache24\htdocs>python mssql_odbc.py** 
Results will be displayed fine. But not at apache http server.

In httpd.conf file:

```
 LoadModule pyodbc_module "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd"
```

Results

```
 httpd: Syntax error on line 571 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't
 locate API module structure `pyodbc_module' in file
 C:/Users/Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd:
 No error
```

So are there any modules or code that should be imported/modified?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache ***500 Internal Error Solved***. Because of ***importing pypyodbc*** instead of *import pyodbc*.

In python shell I was able to connect successfully retrive the results in **python shell** as well as in **Database**.

---