# Initialization Configuration issues to integrate pyodbc with MSSQL Server via Web Browser

Tags: python, sql-server, github, mod-wsgi, pyodbc

Initialization Configuration issues to integrate pyodbc with MSSQL Server via Web Browser

As I'm new to Python Web Programming

*I need to code by **clicking submit button** that should **retrive all the tables** in the person **database** to the **Web Browser via localhost**.*

What should be the server configuration to run with localhost:

- **Apache HTTP Server (or)**
- **WSGI module (or)**
- **Any Other Module/Server (pls Specify)**

Check this below links that I have configured:

1. [By adding one statement import pyodbc causes Internal Server Error in Apache HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587961/by-adding-one-statement-import-pyodbc-causes-internal-server-error-in-apache-htt)
2. [Importing pyodbc results as Internal server error in Apache HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571249/importing-pyodbc-results-as-internal-server-error-in-apache-http-server)
3. [What should be my configuration to load pyodbc module on Apache Server to run simple queries mssql server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573523/what-should-be-my-configuration-to-load-pyodbc-module-on-apache-server-to-run-si)

I had tried with **Apache HTTP Server** with one command **import pyodbc** results in **500 Internal Server Error**. But rest of the things worked fine with POST as well as in Python Shell.

I had coded this way. Kindly had anyone worked with Web Server via localhost let me know what should we need to add/modify with the below code

#### index.html

> ```
> <form action="/cgi-bin/hello_get.py" method="post">
> Click the submmit button to retrive all the tables
> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
> </form>
> ```

#### hello_get.py

> ```
> import pyodbc 
> cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
>                       "Server=DESKTOP-C6RS3DO;"
>                       "Database=demo2016;"
>                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
>
> cursor = cnxn.cursor()
> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM person')
>
> print("Content-Type: text/html")
> print("")
> print("<html><head>")
> print("")
> print("</head><body>")
> for row in cursor:
>     print('row = %r' % (row,))
>
> print("Hello from Python.")
> print("</body></html>")
>
> cursor.close()
> cnxn.close()
> ```

Do I need any extra modules and code from the above code?

#### error.log

> ```
> [cgi:error] [pid 9344:tid 1264] [client ::1:52332] AH01215:
>
> End of script output before headers: hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> Traceback (most recent call last):\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> File "C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\hello_get.py", line 6, in <module>\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> import pyodbc\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> ImportError: No module named pyodbc\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> ```

But whenever try to load the module from **httpd.config** by adding

```
 LoadModule pyodbc_module
 "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd"
```

and restarting the server results in **httpd -k restart**

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 576 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `pyodbc_module' in file C:/Users/Vitriv-Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd: No error
```

Comment: Can you include the error from your Apache logs for the 500 error? That'll tell us what it isn't able to do. I'm guessing it is an issue with importing pyodbc if your CGI settings are correct. Also, you don't need semicolons in Python after `cursor.close();` and `cnxn.close();`. :)

Comment: Thanks for your concern. @FlipperPA 

That's true its ImportError: No module named pyodbc.
Path has been correctly mentioned.
After pip install pyodbc. File automatically created. Still the issue has not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache ***500 Internal Error Solved***. Because of ***importing pypyodbc***.
In python shell I was able to connect successfully retrive the results in **python shell** as well as **MSSQL Server 2017**.

---

**ex.py**

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/Vitriv-Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages')
    import pypyodbc
    import cgi, cgitb

    # Create instance of FieldStorage
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    # Get data from fields
    first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
    last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

    print("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
    print("<html>")
    print("<head>")
    print("<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>")
    print("</head>")
    print("<body>")


    print("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)) 
    cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}', server='DESKTOP-C6RS3DO', database='demo2016', Trusted_Connection='Yes')

    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM person')
    for row in cursor:
        print('row = %r' % (row,))
    print("<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name))   
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.close()

    print("</body>")
    print("</html>")
```

**Index.html**

```
<form action="ex.py" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that Apache can't find the Python path. Don't forget, Apache runs as a different user on your system. If Apache runs as a user called `www-user`, then `www-user` needs to be able to import `pyodbc`.

There are two possible solutions here, if you want to stick with CGI instead of going to a full WSGI app.

First, in your Python script, you may be able to do this before any import statements:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\path\to\python-site-packages\')
```

Or, in your Apache configuration:

```
SetEnv PYTHONPATH "c:\path\to\python-site-packages\"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Tried the above two methods. It didn't work instead I tried with pypyodbc it worked. But there was an connection problem. Will you able to solve this. @FlipperPA Thanks in advice

Comment: Check this links also [click_here_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670856/connecting-to-mssql-server-2017-from-apache-http-server-via-python-script)                     [click_here_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672851/how-to-print-exception-raised-in-python-via-web-browser)